# Writing QuickTime files manually

Tags: quicktime, codec, avi

In the app I'm working on, there's an AVIRecord class that manually write AVI headers and JPEG frames into a video files. They are .avi files with MJPEG codec, according to my media player (using KLite codec pack).

My question is: is this AVI compressed or uncompressed? Because the file size is basically sum of all the jpeg frames.

Can I write a similar code to produce a .mov file (Quicktime format)? By similar i mean: writing headers to the file, putting each frames manually into the files.

The app I am working on is supposed to save the jpeg stream from a IP Cam and save it under quicktime format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most file formats like AVI, MOV do not compress the video and audio bitstreams present in them. File formats are used to store video and audio decodeable units with associated metadata like timestamps. So when you add JPEGs to AVI file, it does not get compressed any further.

You can create MOV file with MJPEG video, similar to way you have been able to create AVI file with MJPEG video. However you would need creator for MOV (similar to the one you have for AVI).

MOV file format has been specified by Apple. A version of the format is available at http://developer.apple.com/standards/qtff-2001.pdf